# How do I NSLog an NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

With the code pasted below, I am trying to log an NSDate. What am I doing wrong here?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *todaysDate;
todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",formatter);
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"The date is %@", todaysDate);` -- Of course the date will be logged in long format and UTC timezone, so you need to understand that.  To use a formatter you'd do `NSLog(@"The date is %@", [formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate]);`.

Comment: Unrelated but use `yyyy` for the year not `YYYY`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063068/weird-behavior-when-creating-an-nsdate-of-january-the-1st-and-the-2nd for details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
  NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate]);
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing wrong is you haven't done anything to associate the date with the formatter. So, you would want to do something like this:

```
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@", [formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate];
```

The `NSDate` doesn't know anything about formatting (just date information), and the `NSDateFormatter` doesnt really know anything about dates, just how to format them. So you have to use methods like `-stringFromDate:` to actually format the date for pretty human-readable display.

If what you need is to just see the date information and don't need a particular format, you don't need a formatter to log a date:

```
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@", todaysDate);
```

Will work fine to give you the `-description` of the `NSDate` object. I wouldn't use this for anything you display to the user (do use an `NSDateFormatter` for that), but this is handy if you're just debugging and need to see information about an `NSDate` object.

Answer (score 4):

Complete example:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:today]);
    [formatter release];
```