# Date formatter not giving the desired output in ios

Tags: ios, date

I am receiving a string of date from server and trying to format it according to my time zone. But its not working!
What I have done:

```
NSString *dateStr = data.createdDate;
NSDate *old =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

where `date.createdDate` is the value which I am receiving from the server and its in the format:

**2016-05-13 11:38:21.0**

So I have created my `dateFormatter` in such a way:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.0";
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

**And the output:**

value received from server: 2016-05-13 11:38:21.0

The Current Time is 2016.05.13 19:19:15.0

The old time in current date format: 2016-05-13 04:38:21 +0000

**Im now in GMT+7 timezone. The time from server is of GMT+0, so at GMT+7 the time should be like 18:38:21**

Comment: how did you print the output? are you nslog of NSData object.?

Comment: the nslog of nsdata object that not return correct output do nslog like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521340/how-do-i-nslog-an-nsdate

Comment: comeon,  the problem is not in NSLog!!! i am doing exactly the way the link suggested.

Comment: Try with setting Time Zone - dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

Comment: i have already set the timezone in the formatter: NSTimeZone systemTimeZone @Pushpa

Comment: Have you try with setting "UTC" time zone?

Comment: As per my point of view, @Pushpa is correct, You can check with UTC or GMT+0 and then print the output.

Comment: Yes @NSAnant because i faced same issue before and resolved by setting time zone as "UTC".

Comment: But i need to change the time according to systemtime so its not fixed like changing the time according to GMT+7. @Pushpa

Comment: @Fay007, did you set the timezone while sending the date to server ?

Comment: The string you are getting from the server doesn't contain any time zone information, so the date formatter will interpret it in the Timezone you specify, which in your case is UTC+7. Then when you print it out in UTC you are getting a time that is 7 hours earlier, but it is the same time; 04:38UTC = 11:38UTC+7. Since the time string you get from the server is actually a UTC time, you need to tell the date formatter this as other have pointed out. The "+0000" means UTC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what i did, i created a dateformatter for GMT 0 and have converted both the time in the same timezone:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.0";
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZonetimeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

 NSString *dateStr = data.createdDate;
 NSDate *old =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```